# Kinvey Public File Upload

Tags: objective-c, xcode, file, kinvey

I'm trying to upload files that every user of the app can see but it looks like the uploaded files are private and only the their creator can download or stream them.

Here's the code I use to upload the file in the view controller:

```
    StatusShareUpdate* update = [[StatusShareUpdate alloc]init];
    update.attachment = image;

    [self.store saveObject:update withCompletionBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {


    } withProgressBlock:nil];
```

---

**StatusShareUpdate.h**

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage* attachment;
```

**StatusShareUpdate.m**

```
- (NSDictionary *)hostToKinveyPropertyMapping {

    return @{@"attachment": @"attachment"};
}

+ (NSDictionary *)kinveyPropertyToCollectionMapping {

    return @{@"attachment":KCSFileStoreCollectionName};
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the appropriate ACL. [Docs clearly](http://devcenter.kinvey.com/ios/guides/files) states that:

> By default the file will only be available to the creating user.

Long story short you need to add the appropriate metadata like the example in docs link:

```
let metadata = KCSMetadata()
metadata.setGloballyReadable(true)
```